# Bypass of Access Restrictions in Apache Cordova iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, whitelist

Recently Apache Cordova announced that iOS contains 2 methods to bypass the URL access restrictions provided by the whitelist. An attacker can use any of the 2 methods to load malicious resources in an app that uses a whitelist to only load trusted resources.

As i am new to Cordova, can anyone please provide information how much the above issue will impact the existing application and how.I am using Cordova ios version 3.5.0.

Comment: Can you post the announce? I am curious about it.

Comment: Check  this link  https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2016/04/27/security.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it says in the link, this problem allows to inject malicious code into your app, as this involve plugins invocations. This can be used to retrieve all the information that you can extract from your app.

This only can be performed through external links, you if you dont have links to external websites, or paths that you are not controlling, you are protected.

Also, I don't know about the extension of this backdoor, and maybe few people know it, but if you want to be sure, just update to the latest version of cordova-ios.

Comment: Del, as my application involves chat, sending link over chat will give any security related issue as you said links external websites will cause issue.